# How do I show an interstitial ad when an application closes?

Tags: android, admob, ads, interstitial

I have this code, and works perfectly, but the ad is showed when i start the app, and i want to show the ad when I press back(to exit app) and press yes.  So when finish(); happened, I want to show my interstitial ad.

```
package inter.ad;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.ads.*;
import com.google.ads.AdRequest.ErrorCode;



public class MainActivity extends Activity implements AdListener {

  private InterstitialAd interstitial;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Create the interstitial
    interstitial = new InterstitialAd(this, "my ad id");

    // Create ad request
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();

    // Begin loading your interstitial
    interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);

    // Set Ad Listener to use the callbacks below
    interstitial.setAdListener(this);
  }

  @Override
  public void onReceiveAd(Ad ad) {
    Log.d("OK", "Received ad");
    if (ad == interstitial) {
      interstitial.show();
    }
  }

@Override
public void onDismissScreen(Ad arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onFailedToReceiveAd(Ad arg0, ErrorCode arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onLeaveApplication(Ad arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onPresentScreen(Ad arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}



public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        exitByBackKey();

        //moveTaskToBack(false);

        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
protected void exitByBackKey() {

    AlertDialog alertbox = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    .setMessage("Do you want to Exit?")
    .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        // do something when the button is clicked
        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {

            finish();
            //close();


        }
    })

    .setNeutralButton("Rate us!", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        // do something when the button is clicked
        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {

             {
                Uri uri = Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + getPackageName());
                Intent goToMarket = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
                try {
                    startActivity(goToMarket);
                } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Couldn´t launch Google Play", 
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }


        }
    })

    .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        // do something when the button is clicked
        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                       }
    })
      .show();
    }
 }
```

Comment: What makes  you think that the *user* wants you to display an interstitial ad when they use BACK to exit your activity?

Comment: @CommonsWare i though could be less annoying if i put it when he close the app (at least for me it is). When do you think is less annoying? I have an FlashLight app.  ?

Comment: @CommonsWare and some people put it BEFORE the user press exit, this is REALLY annoying D:
But i want your opinion about when i should put my interstitial ad. :)

Comment: A quick search on `flashlight` on the Play Store shows 240 entries, and that's before a "Show More" button shows up (and I did not feel like counting further). How are you planning on marketing your flashlight app, to convince people to install yours versus others? How do your ads mesh with your marketing plan? I would worry less about when and where to show ads and worry a lot more about why you are writing the app in the first place. Lots of competition and limited revenue makes for a difficult business model.

Comment: @CommonsWare lol man, you sound mad, really. Dont worry, i have other apps too, i put the example of a flashlight to say you what kind of app i have..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't do this.

Interstitial ads are fine for when you're staying in the app, but I guarantee when you try to spam them as they exit the app, their fingers will stray very quickly to the "uninstall" button.

If you want to do things when the activity is leaving focus, it belongs in `onPause()`, `onStop()` or `onDestroy()` depending on the level of control you need.

Take a look at the [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/stopping.html) on exactly how to do this.

Comment: "when the app is going away" -- those events are for when the *activity* is going away.

Comment: hmm, thanks for the recommendation, i have a FlashLight App, do you say its better if it appears when the app was just launched? i think is annoying :S

Comment: @CommonsWare I'll clarify

Comment: @CommonsWare I clarified the verbiage

Answer (score 3):

I am not suggesting you to do this. Pleas read this blog of google

https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6201362?hl=en

My 2 applications are rejected due to this. Please don't do that.